# Compiling socket code for both Windows and Linux

Tags: c++, winsockets

I am writing a C++ program that uses sockets. I want my program to run on both Windows and Linux.

- On Windows, I need to use:

> Winsock2.h

- On Linux, I need to use:

> arpa/inet.h

How can I define my C++ program to run on different platforms, and how to include `<arpa/inet.h>` while I use Visual Studio on Windows?

Please give me an example!

Comment: You cant make a single program executable that runs on multiple platforms. You need to make separate executables for each platform. You can create multiple projects and share source code between them. Or use a compiler that can output executables for multiple platforms from a single project (Visual Studio on Windows can't make Linux executables). But either way, you need to use `#ifdef`/`#ifndef` statements to wrap platform-specific code, such as `#include` statements. Most compilers define values that can be checked for to identify which platform is being compiled for.

Comment: You may be interested to know that there is a [Networking TS](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4711.pdf) nearing publication, although it may be a while before your favorite standard library implementations support it.

Comment: And while you wait for networking to be added to the next C++ standard, you can use Boost::Asio on which it is based. See http://www.boost.org . Asio support Win32, Linux and several other others so you can easily write an application that runs cross-platform with a single code base.